# C# .NET httpClient Response

Tags: c#, http

I am trying to disable the response received from HTTP requests that I send with .NET's httpClient library for security reasons, and I can't find an answer on how to deal with that problem...

I'm using the httpClient to send a post method to another .NET service. So far what I have succeeded in doing is to return an empty response back.

I am trying to send an image from one server to another, here is the sendnding server's code:

```
public async void SendImage(byte[] buffer, string name)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        HttpContent content = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/bmp");
        await client.PostAsync(SERVER_URI, content);
    }
}
```

Here is my receiving server's code:

```
public void ReceiveImage(Stream req)
{
    Image img = Bitmap.FromStream(req);
    byte[] byteImage;

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        img.Save(ms, img.RawFormat);
        byteImage = ms.ToArray();
    }

    // image saving logic
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is that the sendImage function will not get a response after sending the request, that the reciveImage will not send response.

Is there any way that I can disable the HTTP response received after sending the image with .NET's httpClient?

Comment: What do you mean by "disable". Why don't you just ignore the response by not assigning it to a variable?

Comment: HTTP is a request-response scenario. I don't understand what you mean by disable the response... Are you trying to fire and forget?

Comment: Perhaps your question could be made more clear with an small example demonstrating the problem.  How are you using your `HttpClient` object and what are you trying to change about that?

Comment: I have edited the question that you could better understand the problem I'm dealing with

Comment: @saghisepton why can't you just send a empty 200 response back? It doesn't make sense you cannot do that without further explaining the issue.

Comment: Is the problem that the ReceiveImage image saving logic is slow and that you don't want to wait for that to complete before sending the response to unblock the client? I can't think why else this would be a problem. Why specifically do you need the client to not wait for a success or failure response, and why do you need the server to hide this from the client?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: These are two seperated windows services running on different servers and the communication between the services has to be a one direction connection for security reasons, therefore i cabt receive a response back from the receiveImage function because the communication will no longer be one direction connection.